# Radius of semicircle inscribing $5$ congruent circles of radius $r$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There are $5$ congruent circles with radius $r$ inscribed in a semicircle as shown in the below diagram. What is the radius of the semicircle?

[image]

My attempt:

If the min distance between circle $C_2$ and $C_3$ is $2x$, $C_2C_3 = 2 (r + x)$

$C_2C_5 = C_3C_5 = 2r$

Perpendicular from $C_5$ to the line $C_2C_3$ = $r+h$ then

$(r+h)^2 + (r+x)^2 = (2r)^2$

If I get one more equation in $x, h, r$, I can find $x$ and $h$ in terms of $r$.

If we extend $C_1C_4$ and $C_3C_5$, they will meet at point $M$, with $MC_2$ perpendicular to line $C_1C_2$. While I know $C_1C_2 = 2(r+x)$, I am not sure I can express $C_2M$ in terms of $r$ and $h$.

I also tried using trigonometry but could not find the radius of the bigger circle.

I would appreciate any directional help or solution.

Comment: You can try solving using similar triangles. Point $M$ will be the center of a circle on top.

Comment: Can I not solve using Pythagoras? May be I am choosing wrong triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Once you prove $OM = ON$ which is easy to establish (see my alternate solution), the method you are trying can be completed using $\triangle OJM, \triangle ONI, \triangle CMN$.

WLOG, assume $r = 1$

$OM^2 = 4(1+x)^2+1$

$ON^2 = (1+x)^2+(2+h)^2$

As $OM = ON$,
$3(1+x)^2 + 1 = (2+h)^2$ ...(i)

$CN^2 = (1+x)^2+(1+h)^2$

i.e. $(1+x)^2 = 4 - (1+h)^2$ ...(ii)

Substituting (ii) in (i) and solving, $OM = 2\sqrt2$.

So ratio of radius of semicircle to radius of smaller circle $= 2\sqrt2+1$.

Alternate solution using similar triangles -

say, $\angle MOJ = \theta$

If midpoint of $MN$ is point $P$, $\angle MOP = \theta, \angle MON = 2\theta$

$\angle MNO = \angle NMO = 90^0 - \theta, \angle MOQ = 90^0-\theta$

So, $\triangle OMN \sim \triangle QOM$

$\dfrac {OM}{MN} = \dfrac {QM}{OM}$

$OM = \sqrt{(QM)(MN)} = 2\sqrt2 r$

Desired radius $= 2\sqrt2 r + r = r(2\sqrt2+1)$

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand your comment. I should have thought of the Pythagoras one - I chose wrong triangles.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Introduce $R$ as the radius of the semicircle.

From triangle $OC_2C_4$:

$$OC_4^2=OC_2^2+C_2C_4^2-2OC_2OC_4\cos(90^\circ + \alpha)$$

$$(R-r)^2=r^2+(2r)^2+2r(2r)\sin\alpha$$

$$R^2-2Rr=4r^2+4r^2\sin\alpha\tag{1}$$

From triangle $C_1C_2C_4$:

$$C_1C_2=4r\cos\alpha$$

From triangle $OC_1C_2$:

$$OC_1^2=OC_2^2+C_1C_2^2$$

$$(R-r)^2=r^2+(4r\cos\alpha)^2$$

$$R^2-2Rr=16r^2\cos^2\alpha\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2):

$$4r^2(1+\sin\alpha)=16r^2\cos^2\alpha$$

$$1+\sin\alpha=4(1-\sin^2\alpha)$$

$$4\sin^2\alpha+\sin\alpha-3=0$$

Solve this quadratic equation and take only positive solution:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac 34\tag{3}$$

Now replace (3) into (1):

$$R^2-2Rr=4r^2(1+\frac 34)$$

$$R^2-2Rr-7r^2=0$$

This quadratic equation has only one positive solution:

$$R=r(1+2\sqrt 2)$$